# Want to make a page shows different image every time by Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
<%=
require "mini_magick"
require 'rmagick'

first_image = MiniMagick::Image.new("#{Rails.root}/public/img/summon.png")
second_image = MiniMagick::Image.new("#{Rails.root}/public/img/(1).png")
result = first_image.composite(second_image) do |c|
    c.compose "Over"
    c.geometry "+20+20" 
end
result.write "output.jpg"

%>
```

Hi everybody, I want to make a page shows different image every time by heroku.
But when I check the page, there's nothing, I don't know where's the wrong, can somebody tell me?

Comment: Yes. Because I was trying to combine images, I didn't type too much codes.

Comment: Is your `output.jpg` being correctly generated? If so, what is the path to it? (Where is it located?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that your `<%= %>` block doesn't actually generate any `html` to be rendered. I believe you should be able to do something like:

```
<%=
  require "mini_magick"
  require 'rmagick'

  first_image = MiniMagick::Image.new("#{Rails.root}/public/img/summon.png")
  second_image = MiniMagick::Image.new("#{Rails.root}/public/img/(1).png")
  result = first_image.composite(second_image) do |c|
      c.compose "Over"
      c.geometry "+20+20" 
  end
  result.write "output.jpg"
  image_url('output.jpg')
%>
```

And get your new image to display. (That's assuming that all the above code actually works correctly.) You *might* have to fiddle with `image_url('output.jpg')`, depending on where your image is written to.

But, that's ugly. And there are plenty of things to fix here.

First of all, it seems to me like your `require` statements belong in `config/application.rb`.

Then, the meat of this code doesn't belong in a view, it belongs (minimally) in a controller. Better yet, it would belong in a service. So, let's say you have:

```
#app/services/composite_image_service.rb

class CompositeImageService 

  attr_accessor *%w(
    args
  ).freeze

  class << self 

    def call(args={})
      new.call(args)
    end

  end # Class Methods

  #==============================================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #==============================================================================================

    def initialize(args)
      @args = args
    end

    def call 

      first_image  = MiniMagick::Image.new("#{Rails.root}/public/img/summon.png")
      second_image = MiniMagick::Image.new("#{Rails.root}/public/img/(1).png")

      first_image.composite(second_image) do |c|
        c.compose "Over"
        c.geometry "+20+20" 
      end.write("output.jpg")

    end

end
```

Now, in your controller, where you want to generate a new image, do something like:

```
FooController < ApplicationController

  def some_action
    CompositeImageService.call 
  end

end
```

And then, in your `some_action` view, do something like:

```
<%= image_url 'output.jpg' %>
```

I *think* that ought to do the trick.

And now:

1. Your view is dumb again, the way it should be.
2. Your controller doesn't have to know anything about *how* to generate an image. So, it's pretty dumb, too. Also the way it should be.
3. Your image generation code is in a nice, clean plain-old ruby object that is easy to test.